# C Header Files and ABI

Tags: c, haskell, header-files, abi

I'd like to know how C Header Files and ABIs relate. The sizes of various types are architecture and even compiler-dependent. Then how can one reliably link to a C library?

For a more specific problem: When using Haskell's FFI, one even only uses Haskell types like `CDouble` to define (duplicate the definition of) the C library interface. I don't know where the binary type size information is coming from. What is the trick for making the linking work?

Comment: It's basically guesswork. ;-) At least within the range allowed by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link [https://code.google.com/p/tabi](https://code.google.com/p/tabi/)

It may help you to avoid difficulties with possible ABI differences between Haskell and C.

Answer (score 0):

The library type information comes from magic macros that are run to insert information grabbed from the C compiler by autoconf.

For example, see the definition of `CDouble`here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Foreign.C.Types.html#CDouble

and then see where the `HTYPE_DOUBLE` size comes from in this autoconf input here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/src/include/HsBaseConfig.h.in

Since GHH compiles against the compiler/arch it is compiled with (except in the special cross-compiler modes, which are new and different in ways I'm not fully cognizant of) this makes everything tie out with the ABI properly.